# Sequelize Error - lodash has no method "template"

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I just installed Sequelize and MySQL modules via npm and am running into an error.

I can query my models successfully, but trying to create a new model instance results in an error within the query-generator.js file.

My code:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize')
  , sequelize = new Sequelize('databasename', 'username', 'password');

var User = sequelize.define('users', {
  email: Sequelize.STRING,
  fname: Sequelize.STRING,
  lname: Sequelize.STRING,
});

// WORKS
User.find(1)
  .success(function(user) {
    console.log('User found');
  }).
  error(function(err) {
    console.log('Error locating user', err);
  });

// FAILS
User.create({
  email : 'test@example.com',
  fname : 'John',
  lname : 'Doe'
})
.success(function(user) {
  // Do something
})
.error(function(err) {
  // Do something
});
```

And here's the error

```
~/Project/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:156
      return Utils._.template(query)(replacements)
                 ^
TypeError: Object function lodash(value) {
      // don't wrap if already wrapped, even if wrapped by a different `lodash` constructor
      return (value && typeof value == 'object' && !isArray(value) && hasOwnProperty.call(value, '__wrapped__'))
   ? value
   : new lodashWrapper(value);
} has no method 'template'
at Object.module.exports.QueryGenerator.insertQuery (~/Project/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:156:22)
```

Comment: http://lodash.com/docs#template ?

Comment: I get that lodash has a template method. But the question is, why is the Sequelize package giving me this error? I can't find any other documented cases of it.

Comment: You are using mysql right ? Did you install the mysql package as well?

Comment: Ah you did. which version of sequelize and mysql are you using?

Comment: Sequelize is 1.7.5 and Node MySQL is 2.3.0. I've tried rolling back to previous versions of Sequelize, with no luck. Also tried the Dev branches.

Comment: Interesting, I opened the lodash node module included with Sequelize and the description reads "A private version of Lo-dash lib, without template() method to bypass CSP restrictions"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out my local version of npm was fetching the Emmet specific lodash version. Running

```
npm install lodash
```

fetched this repo https://github.com/emmetio/lodash instead of https://github.com/lodash/lodash

Running

```
npm install lodash --force
```

and reinstall Sequelize corrected my issue.